# Bootstrap multi-line label causing column sizing problems

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Whenever I try to create a label that wraps to the second line, it starts messing up the column placing.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ReqPhone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="Phone" value="<?php echo $ophone ?>">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-validation="required" name="ReqPhone" id="ReqPhone" placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength="20">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ReqPhone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Are you the Nominee’s Direct Supervisor?</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="Phone" value="<?php echo $ophone ?>">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select an Option...</option>
                <option value="one">Yes</option>
                <option value="two">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ReqPhone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Supervisor's Name:</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="Phone" value="<?php echo $ophone ?>">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select an Option...</option>
                <option value="one">Yes</option>
                <option value="two">No</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the result I'm getting. I'm just trying to get these to stack properly while having a multi line label.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I noticed all your labels are for the same input ("ReqPhone").
Second, what's the class you're using for the form? Try using `form class='form-horizontal'`

Maybe this will help:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="ReqPhone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Phone Number:</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="Phone" value="<?php echo $ophone ?>">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-validation="required" name="ReqPhone" id="ReqPhone" placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength="20">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Nominee" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Are you the Nominee’s Direct Supervisor?</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="Phone" value="<?php echo $ophone ?>">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select class="form-control" id='Nominee'>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select an Option...</option>
            <option value="one">Yes</option>
            <option value="two">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="NameSupervisor" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Supervisor's Name:</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="Phone" value="<?php echo $ophone ?>">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select class="form-control" id='NameSupervisor'>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select an Option...</option>
            <option value="one">Yes</option>
            <option value="two">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's in a `form-horizontal`..

```
<div class="form form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ReqPhone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Phone Number:</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="Phone" value="<?php echo $ophone ?>">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-validation="required" name="ReqPhone" id="ReqPhone" placeholder="Phone Number" maxlength="20">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ReqPhone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Are you the Nominee’s Direct Supervisor?</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="Phone" value="<?php echo $ophone ?>">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select an Option...</option>
                    <option value="one">Yes</option>
                    <option value="two">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ReqPhone" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Supervisor's Name:</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="Phone" value="<?php echo $ophone ?>">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select an Option...</option>
                    <option value="one">Yes</option>
                    <option value="two">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/lmk2IyMz14